# SQL Like Operator

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause, sql-like

Expected Output:

[image]

How can we run a query that returns "Robot" followed by a year between 2000 and 2099? (So 2015 is a valid value at the end, but 2123 is not.)

[image]

Comment: Are those years well-formed, no `Robot 20bla`? `WHERE col LIKE '%Robot 20__%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer:

```
SELECT id, name FROM robots WHERE name LIKE '%Robot 20%_%'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name FROM robots WHERE name LIKE '%Robot 20__%'
```

If there might be other characters after `20` you need `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT name FROM robots 
WHERE name REGEXP 'Robot 20[0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: Sir, Not getting the expected output.

Comment: @Kusum: After modifying your question the `REGEXP` should still return the expected result. If not, please show what's wrong. The `LIKE` might return `Robot 20qq`, too.

Comment: Sir,
 First i used this query---**SELECT name FROM robots WHERE name LIKE '%Robot 20__%'** 
it gives the result--- **id**  **name**
1 Robot 2000


There after I used the 2nd query-----**SELECT name FROM robots 
WHERE name REGEXP 'Robot 20[0-9][0-9]'**---- No output found

Comment: @Kusum: Fiddle doesn't work right now, but this a correct regex, `Robot` , a space ' ' , `20`, two digits.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
SELECT name FROM robots WHERE name LIKE '%Robot 20%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, name FROM robots WHERE name LIKE '%robot 20%' ORDER BY id
```

Comment: I used the above query but not getting the expected result.

Comment: **id**   **name**
1 Robot 2000

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name from robots WHERE name LIKE "%robot 200%";
```